# Regex patter to exclude whitspacs\es

Tags: java, regex, datetime, java-time, datetime-parsing

I have the lines of the following format

```
9/14/2021 6:01:14 PM   42 (3224)   Receive rate: 39338 B/s
9/14/2021 6:01:29 PM   92 (940)   Receive rate: 215363 B/s
```

I need to extract 2 pieces of data from here: timestamp and the actual rate, e.g.

```
9/14/2021 6:01:14 PM, 39338
9/14/2021 6:01:29 PM, 215363
```

I am using grouping and came up with the following pattern:

```
^(.*)\s*[0-9]*\s+\([0-9]+\)\s+Receive\s+rate:\s+([0-9]+)
```

With such a pattern, I successfully return my second group (39338, 215363), but for the first group it goes too far beyond the AM/PM point and the first group becomes `9/14/2021 6:01:14 PM   42`.

If I change the pattern to

```
^(.*)   [0-9]*\s+\([0-9]+\)\s+Receive\s+rate:\s+([0-9]+) -> 3 spaces instead of the first \s*
```

it matches as expected, but there is no guarantee there will be 3 spaces, so I need to use whitespace char with **zero or more**.

Answer (score 2):

#### Retrieve the Date-Time and Receive-Rate parts separately.

I suggest you retrieve the Date-Time and Receive-Rate parts separately. For retrieving the Date-Time part, you can use the rich `java.time` API and then you can use the Java RegEx API to retrieve the Receive-Rate part.

#### Retrieve the Date-Time part

You can use [`DateTimeFormatter#parse(CharSequence, ParsePosition)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-java.text.ParsePosition-) to parse the string to a `TemporalAccessor` from which `LocalDateTime` can be retrieved.

Learn more about the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

#### Retrieve the Receive-Rate part

You can use the [regex](https://regex101.com/r/uTrhYG/1), `(?<=(?:Receive rate: ))\d+(?=(?: B\/s))` where `(?<=(?:Receive rate: ))` and `(?=(?: B\/s))` have been used as the positive lookbehind and positive lookahead patterns respectively.

**Complete Demo:**

```
import java.text.ParsePosition;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test
        Stream.of(
                "9/14/2021 6:01:14 PM   42 (3224)   Receive rate: 39338 B/s",
                "9/14/2021 6:01:29 PM   92 (940)   Receive rate: 215363 B/s"
        )
        .forEach(s -> System.out.printf(
                            "Timestamp: %s, Receive rate: %s%n", 
                            getTimestampPart(s),
                            getReceiveRate(s)
        ));
    }

    static String getTimestampPart(String str) {
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("M/d/uuuu h:mm:ss a", Locale.ENGLISH);
        return LocalDateTime.from(dtf.parse(str, new ParsePosition(0))).format(dtf);
    }

    static String getReceiveRate(String str) {
        Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(?<=(?:Receive rate: ))\\d+(?=(?: B\\/s))").matcher(str);
        return matcher.find() ? matcher.group() : "";
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Timestamp: 9/14/2021 6:01:14 PM, Receive rate: 39338
Timestamp: 9/14/2021 6:01:29 PM, Receive rate: 215363
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/LIAXum)

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Used regex:

```
"^(\\d{1,2}/\\d{1,2}/\\d{4}\\s.*?)\\s{3}.+?\\s{3}Receive\\s+rate:\\s+(\\d+)"
```

Regex in context and testbench:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "9/14/2021 6:01:14 PM   42 (3224)   Receive rate: 39338 B/s\n"
            + "9/14/2021 6:01:29 PM   92 (940)   Receive rate: 215363 B/s";

    String regex = "^(\\d{1,2}/\\d{1,2}/\\d{4}\\s.*?)\\s{3}.+?\\s{3}Receive\\s+rate:\\s+(\\d+)";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
    while(matcher.find()) {
        System.out.printf("Time stamp: '%s' || Rate: '%s'%n", matcher.group(1), matcher.group(2));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Time stamp: '9/14/2021 6:01:14 PM' || Rate: '39338'
Time stamp: '9/14/2021 6:01:29 PM' || Rate: '215363'
```

More regular-expression constructs can be found here:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Answer (score -1):

You can be in this case more specific:

```
(\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{1,4}\s+\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}\s+PM)\s+\d+\s+\(\d*?\)\s+Receive\s+rate\:\s+(\d*)\s+B/s\s*\n
```

Where:

- `\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{1,4}\s+` is the first date pattern with `\d{1,2}` being "at least one but at maximum 2 digits" - followed by
- `\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}\s+` which is the hh:mm:ss block
- `PM\s+` the PM
- `\d+\s+\(\d*?\)` the digit blocks
- `Receive\s+rate\:\s+(\d*)` the "Receive rate" with the following number blocks
- `B/s\s*\n` the end

Or lazier:

```
(^[0-9/]*\s+[0-9:]+\s+PM)\s+[0-9 \(\)]+?\s+Receive\s+rate:\s+([0-9]+)\s+B/s\n
```

With:

- `^[0-9/]*\s+` group of numbers or `/` followed by whitespace, then
- `[0-9:]+\s+` group of numbers or `:` followed by whitespace
- `[0-9 \(\)]+?\s+` group of numbers, empty space or `(` or `)` - non-greedy followed by whitespace
- `Receive\s+rate:\s+` literally what should stand there with whitespaces
- `([0-9]+)\s+B/s\n` the number block and the rest

Comment: Explicitly matching `PM` only seems inadvisable, since that will be either `AM` or `PM` in timestamps.

Comment: True. `(P|A)M` should be taken then.

Comment: Or, slightly shorter,  `[AP]M`.